# updating multiple select tags with jquery (mobile)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have multiple `<select/>`  tags i would like to synchronize so that when one is changed, they all change.  They are all part of a navbar header for a jquery mobile page(s).  My selector is this:  `$("header select")`.

I hooked up the `change` event like this:

```
var statusselect = $("header select");

var statusevent = function (event) {

    statusselect.off("change");

    statusselect.val(event.target.value);

    statusselect.on("change", statusevent);

    try {
        statusselect.selectmenu("refresh");
    } 
    catch(e) {

    } 
};

statusselect.on("change", statusevent);
```

This only works if i have that `try/catch` statement.  If i take out the `try/catch` and its inner code, the text of the `<select/>` updates only after the first change.  After that, the event is fired correctly and all values passed are correct, but the text never updates (showing the correctly selected option).

If I take out the `try/catch` and leave the `statusselect.selectmenu("refresh")`, an exception is thrown stating the object had yet to be initialized.

So im left scratching my head: Why do i need to throw an exception in order for the `<select/>` to change its text?  Is it because the exception is being thrown for the `<select/>`s that are not in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you answered your own question, the `refresh` method is meant to refresh a widget (`selectmenu` in this case) that has already been initialized, in your case the initialization for the selects that are on other pages hasn't taken place yet (enhancement takes place in the [pageinit](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html) `event`) so you would need to initialize it first which you should be able to do manually by calling `.selectmenu()`.

Comment: ok, so call `selectmenu()` in the pageinit event?  Or before?

Comment: According to the JQM docs most widgets should "auto-initialize" themselves based on the `pageinit event`, so you shouldn't need to so once the event has fired. Whats happening by you is that the event hasn't fired yet, if you want to call it manually then you can do so before the event or just stick it in the catch block.

Comment: ahh, ok, thats what i thought you were saying.  Thank you!